# Exposing a function with char** argument in boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a function whose signature is

```
parser create_parser(int, char **)
```

Where "parser" is a class. Now I want to expose this function to my Python module via boost Python so I did this:

```
boost::python::def ("create_parser", (parser(*)(int, char **)) create_parser);
```

But when I call it in my python as:

```
create_parser(2, ['a', 'b'])
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    create_parser(int, list)
did not match C++ signature:
    create_parser(int, char**)
```

Is there something specific to a character array that i need to do to get it exposed in the Python code?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a fancier way, but I'd write an additional function which takes a python list, validates that it only contains strings, and transforms it into a `char**` and calls the original function. Expose that instead of the original function. Hard tell you much more, since it's not really clear what the expectations of `create_parser` are regarding the lifetime and ownership of the `char**` parameter.

Comment: @Jatinshravan did you manage to solve this? I'm currently facing the same problem